# Getting Ping from Java to Erlang

Tags: java, erlang, pid, erlang-otp

I recently posted a similar Erlang-Java related  question called "[Java to Erlang Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132554/java-to-erlang-messages)".

I have made some progress sense then, and i've gotten a stable connection up-and-running between the two languages (thanks to a older question that i found on stackoverflow).

But my problem is now that i can only send a message to Java from Erlang and receive it, Im having trouble making a return message.

What do i have to create in order to send a message from java, when can i send it?

This is some of my code for receiving.

```
    try {
        node = new OtpNode("javambox@localhost", "gui"); // name, cookie
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.exit(-1);
    }

...

OtpMbox mbox = node.createMbox("mbox");

    while (true) {

        OtpErlangObject o = null;

        try {
            o = mbox.receive();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find an example here 
http://pdincau.wordpress.com/2010/01/07/how-to-create-a-java-erlang-node-with-jinterface/

Comment: Thanks for the link, great stuff!